# Message not posted on Facebook, Twitter, and Linked in (using socialauth library 4.4)

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, socialauth

I am trying to post message on Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin, but I am getting exception in my log cat i.e "Java.lang.nullPointerException" and "Message not posted" .No Toast is also executing as there are two Toast in **MessageListener** class "**execute()** method" one is "message posted" and another one is "message not posted".I have highligted these Toast in my code, I have tried my best but its not working even i have generated new keys also but still getting the same problem.
a
Please help me !!
Looking forward for reply..

Here is my code
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup Parent) {

```
View vi=convertView;
 final ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
 if (vi==null) {
     vi= inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_items, null);
     Log.e("adapter","adaper set");
     final LinearLayout shareBar=(LinearLayout)                    vi.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutshareBar);

        adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());  

        adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook_share);
        adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER,  R.drawable.tweet_button);
        adapter.addProvider(Provider.LINKEDIN, R.drawable.linkedin_share);

        adapter.enable(shareBar);


}      


}
```

**ResponseListener Class**

```
class ResponseListener implements DialogListener
  {
String msg;

@Override
public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.d("ShareBar", e.getMessage());


}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("ShareBar", "Authentication Cancelled");

}

@Override
public void onBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
       dialog.setTitle("Share Message");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);

        final EditText editText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.shareText);
        Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.updatebutton);    
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                msg=editText.getText().toString();
                adapter.updateStatus(msg,new MessageListener(),true); 
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();


}


}
```

**MessageListener Class**

```
private final class MessageListener implements SocialAuthListener<Integer> {

@Override
public void onExecute(String provider, Integer t) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Integer status = t;
       if (status.intValue() == 200 || status.intValue() == 201 ||status.intValue() == 204)
       **Toast.makeText(activity, "Message posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**
       else
       **Toast.makeText(activity, "Message not posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**
       Log.e("Execute", "I am onExecute");

}

@Override
public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(activity,"i m error",1000).show();

}
}
```

Comment: i think you have not created your secret key and consumer key correctly.,check that again..

Comment: I have tried that also and my key is correct because if i work with a new  seperate application with the same key which i generated for this application then it works .Message get posted correctly. I tried this for Facebook.

Comment: @kirtiHudda try as per my answer and let me know

Comment: @Simple Plan its written there in my getView()..actually i put only the code i.e related to share function..I have lots of thing in my getView() thats why i didn't put my complete getView().

Comment: initialize socialauth adapter in on create , using in getview is wrong practice and that may be causing the issue.